# Processing in inner class

Tags: java, processing

While I was programming Processing in Java, I wondered: "Can I run a sketch in inner class?", so I scripted code like this.

```java
package sampletext;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class OuterClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main("sampletext.OuterClass.InnerClass");
    }

    public class InnerClass extends PApplet {
        public InnerClass() {}

        // TODO something...
    }
}
```

Then I got `ClassNotFoundException` at `PApplet.main("sampletext.OuterClass.InnerClass");`.
I was expecting it would work, but it didn't. (and I also tried `"sampletext.OuterClass$InnerClass"`. it didn't work, though.)

Can someone say what is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you post the code for `PApplet`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: can you post the code for `PApplet` class ?

Comment: Oh, do you want this? https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/index.html?processing/core/PApplet.html

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I found a solution

```java
package sampletext;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class OuterClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Class<?> c = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("sampletext.OuterClass$InnerClass");
        PApplet.main(c); // These ones
    }

    public static class InnerClass extends PApplet {
        public InnerClass() {}

        // TODO something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to simply do `PApplet.main(InnerClass.class)`? I don't have processing installed on the machine I'm on so I can't verify right now.